# extracting information from json

Tags: python, json, facebook-graph-api, csv

How to extract id, likes, name, category, created_time from this josn file, which comes from Facebook Graph API

```
{
  "rows" : [
    {
      "id" : "145907652175534",
      "interests" : "{\"likes\":150319,\"id\":\"145907652175534\"}",
      "name" : "The Lion, the Witch and the Wardrobe",
      "category" : "Book",
      "created_time" : "2013-12-19T16:15:01+0000"
    },
    {
      "id" : "190616700999052",
      "interests" : "{\"likes\":1027992,\"id\":\"190616700999052\"}",
      "name" : "C. S. Lewis",
      "category" : "Author",
      "created_time" : "2013-12-19T16:14:47+0000"
    },
    {
      "id" : "577324418996792",
      "interests" : "{\"likes\":1672,\"id\":\"577324418996792\"}",
      "name" : "Big Data",
      "category" : "Community",
      "created_time" : "2013-12-19T16:14:38+0000"
    },
    {
      "id" : "134488303306371",
      "interests" : "{\"likes\":5718,\"id\":\"134488303306371\"}",
      "name" : "Big Data University",
      "category" : "Computers/internet website",
      "created_time" : "2013-12-19T16:14:21+0000"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far? You've tagged this with `csv`, did you want to create a CSV file with the information?

Comment: Yes. I want to have five columns (id, likes, name, category, created_time). Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is a standard library called `json` that you will be interested in:

```
import json

jstring = ##insert your json string here###

data = json.loads(jstring)
```

`data` will then be a python object of nested dictionaries/lists.  You should experiment from there and figure out how to access what you want.

If you want to write a CSV, you should check out `csv`:

```
import csv

data = ### a list of lists ###

with open('filename.csv', 'w') as f:
    csv.writer(f).writerows(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like:

```
import json

data_list = json.loads(json_data)
ans_list = []
data_list = data['rows']
for row in data_list:
    ans_list.append(row['id'], row['interests'], row['name'], row['category'], row['created_time'])
print(ans_list)
```

Comment: where does `data` come from?  The user has a json string (I presume), not a python object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, how do I access to likes, which is inside interests? For example, I would like to extract 150319, 1027992, 1672, 5718 in a column.

Comment: In `for loop` you can gets `likes` of `interests` like: `row['interests']['likes']`.